# No puedo llamar un método con el mismo objeto

Tags: php

Esto intentando accesar dos veces al mismo método sin tener que crear dos veces el objeto. Hice este código

```
    <?php 
class help{

  public $cn;
  public function __construct(){
    require_once 'connection.php';
    $this->cn = $c;// ahora $cn trae la conexión a la DB
  }


  public function executeQuery( $q ){
    self::__construct(); /*Lo agregué por que según yo estaba tratando de invocar
                          Nuevamente el método sin crear un objeto previo, si
                          se lo quito, me marca como si no existera $cn*/
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    mysqli_set_charset($this->cn, "utf8");
    return mysqli_query( $this->cn, $q );
  }

}

  $h = new help();
  $q = "INSERT INTO FOOBAR (foo_id, bar_id) VALUES('foo','bar')";//inserto un registro
  $r = $h->executeQuery( $q );//Hago algo con ese $r
  $q = "SELECT * FROM FOOBAR";//recupero todos los registros pero truena
  echo $h->executeQuery( json_encode( $q ) );;
 ?>
```

Ahora resulta que el objeto no tiene un constructor, y si no le paso el `self::__construct();` me manda que `$cn` no está declarado.

Como lo soluciono? Tendré que crear dos objetos?

Gracias

**EDITO**

```
<?php
global $c;
$c = mysqli_connect("localhost","foo","bar","myDB");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código del archivo `connection.php`? No queda claro cómo ese archivo devuelve el objeto conexión realmente.

Comment: Listo, pero no creo que sea la conexión

Comment: El código debería funcionar bien sin esta línea: `self::__construct();`, a no ser que esté dando error de conexión. Yo quitaría el atributo `global` a `$cn`, si otro script cambia su valor o cierra la conexión, te encontrarás con una conexión nula, las globales son una mala práctica casi siempre... y en este caso no hay duda de que una global es una pésima práctica.

Answer (score 0):

Ya me ayudaron en el foro inglés, gracias

```
require_once 'connection.php';//Este no
require 'connection.php';//Este si
```

Agrego pregunta liga de [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311948/can%C2%B4t-call-few-times-a-method-same-object-php?noredirect=1#comment87640490_50311948)

Comment: y por que? cual es la diferencia? así tu respuesta será marcada como de baja calidad por favor se claro

Comment: No veo gran diferencia. Una solución correcta sería delegar a tu archivo `connection.php`  todo lo relativo a la conexión, creando una clase `Conexion` dotada de un `getter` que te devuelva el objeto conexión cuando lo necesites. Esa clase sería la que debería establecer el charset y el método `executeQuery` es reinventar la rueda, porque `mysqli` dispone ya de un método `query`.

Comment: Ya les agregué la respuesta del foro inglés.

Comment: aaah pero hay más código dentro de executeQuery, información paja que no tenía nada que ver con la pregunta, @A. Cedano.

Comment: Haya lo que haya, conviene que tengas un código organizado. La query debería ejecutarla una clase que maneja todo lo relativo a la base de datos. Es más, la salida por pantalla debería ser también delegada a una clase que gestione las vistas... algo parecido al modelo `MVC`. O sea, que una vez ejecutada la consulta, el resultado debería ser enviado a la `Vista` para que lo presente.